# AngularJS : Can we share single directive with only two controllers privately but no others controller

Tags: angularjs

I have an application which has multiple controller.

I have created a template directive which I want to share with two controller only but no others.

I know I can make it common so any controller can use but I looking to use it with two controllers privately only.

Directive

```
angular.module('myApp.myController1').directive('myDirective', function() {return {
restrict : 'E',
templateUrl : 'pathTo/myTemplate.html'};});
```

As above directive is for myController1 only

```
angular.module('myApp').directive('myDirective', function() {return {
restrict : 'E',
templateUrl : 'pathTo/myTemplate.html'};});
```

Above directive can be used for all the controller in `myApp`,

But I am curious to know if can make something that can be used by only two, lets say

`myController1` and `myController2` but not by `myController3` all with in `myApp`.

Comment: Directive is not directly dependent on controller .

Comment: what you are going to achieve by doing this?